# sending http requests from client to server inside heroku platform

Tags: node.js, angular, web, heroku

My app is using angular in the client and nodejs as the backend, but I have some problem to configure them properly in production on **heroku**.

In development I run my nodejs server on port 3000 and send all the http requests from the angular client to `http://localhost:3000` and its works very well.
but when I deploy my nodejs server with my angular client files under the dist directory, heroku lifts the server on random port and all my http requests to `http://localhost:3000` failed. how I can determine the node port on heroku or how I can get it in my angular client?

Code on server:

```
let port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port, () => console.log('app listening on port ' 
+ port));
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
```

Code on client:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  serverUrl: 'http://localhost:3000'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can directly use the URL of your backend provided by Heroku. You don't require any port here. Since it'll use port 80 as the default port. `Eg: https://example.herokuapp.com/`

Comment: yes, it's possible, but I thought that sending requests to localhost + port will be much faster that sending http requests to domain name. maybe I am wrong and your way is considered as the best pratice

Comment: As far as I know, in Heroku, there is no way to know on which IP and the port the application has been deployed. It's always better to use domain names. The cloud providers are smart enough to quickly resolve DNS.